# Can you override interface methods with different, but "compatible", signatures?

Tags: php, interface, phpstorm

Consider the following PHP interfaces:

```
interface Item {
    // some methods here
}

interface SuperItem extends Item {
    // some extra methods here, not defined in Item
}

interface Collection {
    public function add(Item $item);
    // more methods here
}

interface SuperCollection extends Collection {
    public function add(SuperItem $item);
    // more methods here that "override" the Collection methods like "add()" does
}
```

I'm using PHPStorm, and when I do this, I get an error in the IDE that basically states the definition for `add()` in `SuperCollection` is not compatible with the definition in the interface it extends, `Collection`.

In one way, I can see this being a problem, as the signature of the method does not match the one it "overrides" *exactly*.  However, I do feel that this would be compatible, as `SuperItem` extends `Item`, so I would view `add(SuperItem)` the same as `add(Item)`.

I'm curious as to if this is supported by PHP (version 5.4 or above), and maybe the IDE has a bug that doesn't properly catch this.

Comment: In 5.3, I get "Fatal error: Declaration of SuperCollection::add() must be compatible with that of Collection::add()". So it looks like PhpStorm is correct. Why do you think that 5.4 might behave differently?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, I'm pretty sure PHP doesn't support this, in any version, and it would rather defeat the point of an interface.

The point of an interface is that it gives you a fixed contract with other code that references the same interface.

For example, consider a function like this:

```
function doSomething(Collection $loopMe) { ..... }
```

This function expects to receive an object that implements the `Collection` interface.

Within the function, the programmer would be able to write calls to methods that are defined in `Collection`, knowing that the object would implement those methods.

If you have an overridden interface like this, then you have a problem with this, because a `SuperCollection` object could be passed into the function. It would work because it also is a `Collection` object due to the inheritance. But then the code in the function could no longer be sure that it knows what the definition of the `add()` method is.

An interface is, by definition, a fixed contract. It is immutable.

As an alternative, you could consider using abstract classes instead of interfaces. This would allow you to override in non-Strict mode, although you'll still get errors if you use Strict Mode, for the same reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I was thinking that this should work in my head, but you helped me see the error in that.

Comment: I have to disagree with this answer.  Interfaces aren't concerned with method definitions or the relationships therein (e.g. `add()`ing an item means you can also `delete()` it).  Their only responsibility is enforcing compatible method signatures (inputs/outputs).  You're correct about them being fixed contracts, but incorrect about the purpose of that contract.  Two classes could very easily implement the same interface and have *totally different* semantics (e.g. `add()` could actually *delete* items in one class and it wouldn't matter as long as the inputs/outputs remain the same type).

Comment: @drrcknlsn altough i don't think it invalidates the explanation, it is very much something to keep in mind.

Comment: @FtDRbwLXw6 It's a matter of interpretation, but I consider the responsibility of an interface to extend to the semantics of the functions, not just the signatures. Many prominent PHP interfaces come with docblocks, e.g. https://github.com/php-fig/log/blob/master/Psr/Log/LoggerInterface.php or https://github.com/php-fig/http-message/blob/master/src/RequestInterface.php . Implementers need to read the docs to ensure that they don't violate the Liskov Substitution Principle. That's an advantage of PHP having nominal, rather than structural, typing.

Answer (score 4):

PHP 7.4, released November 2019 has [improved type variance](https://stitcher.io/blog/new-in-php-74#improved-type-variance-rfc).

The code from the question remains invalid:

```
interface Item {
    // some methods here
}

interface SuperItem extends Item {
    // some extra methods here, not defined in Item
}

interface Collection {
    public function add(Item $item);
    // more methods here
}

interface SuperCollection extends Collection {
    public function add(SuperItem $item); // This will still be a compile error
    // more methods here that "override" the Collection methods like "add()" does
}
```

Because the `Collection` interface guarantees that anything that implements it can accept any object of type `Item` as the parameter of `add`.

However, the following code is valid in PHP 7.4:

```
interface Item {
    // some methods here
}

interface SuperItem extends Item {
    // some extra methods here, not defined in Item
}

interface Collection {
    public function add(SuperItem $item);
    // more methods here
}

interface SuperCollection extends Collection {
    public function add(Item $item); // no problem
    // more methods here that "override" the Collection methods like "add()" does
}
```

In this case `Collection` guarantees that that it can accept any `SuperItem`. Since all `SuperItem`s are `Item`s, `SuperCollection` also makes this guarantee, while also guaranteeing that it can accept any other type of `Item`. This is known as a [Contravariant method parameter type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Contravariant_method_parameter_type).

There is a limited form of type variance in earlier versions of PHP. Assuming other interfaces are as in the question, the `SuperCollection` may be defined as:

```
interface SuperCollection extends Collection {
    public function add($item); // no problem
    // more methods here that "override" the Collection methods like "add()" does
}
```

This can be interpreted as meaning any value whatsoever may be passed to the `add` method. That of course includes all `Item`s, so this is still type safe, or it can be interpreted as meaning that an unspecified class of values, generally documented as `mixed` may be passed and the programmer needs to use other knowledge of exactly what can work with the function.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround I'm using PHPDoc blocks in interfaces.

```
interface Collection {
   /**
    * @param Item $item
    */
    public function add($item);
    // more methods here
}

interface SuperCollection extends Collection {
    /**
    * @param SuperItem $item
    */
    public function add($item);
    // more methods here that "override" the Collection methods like "add()" does
}
```

This way, in case you are properly using interfaces, IDE should help you catch some errors. You can use [similar technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422601/override-return-type-in-phpdoc/36517944#36517944) to override return value types as well.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the methods arguments.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

Comment: Except for the cases when you assign default values to the new arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Extending interface is not allowed to change method definitions. If your SuperItem is extending Item, it should be passing through classes implementing Collection interface without problems.

But based on what you really want to do, you can try:

- Create interface with slightly different methods for SuperItem and implement that:

  ```
  interface SuperCollection extends Collection {
      public function addSuper(SuperItem $superItem);
  }
  ```
- Use decorator pattern to create almost same interface without extending:

  ```
  interface Collection {
      public function add(Item $item);
      // more methods here
  }

  interface SuperCollection {
      public function add(SuperItem $item);
      // more methods here that "override" the Collection methods like "add()" does
  }
  ```

  Then decorator (abstract) class, which will use this interface:

  ```
  class BasicCollection implements Collection {
      public function add(Item $item)
      {
      }
  }

  class DecoratingBasicCollection implements SuperCollection {
      protected $collection;

      public function __construct(Collection $collection)
      {
          $this->collection = $collection;
      }

      public function add(SuperItem $item)
      {
          $this->collection->add($item);
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the IDE. In PHP you cannot override a method. And the compatibility is only in the opposite direction - you can safely expect an instance of the parent class and receive a subclass. But when you expect a subclass, you cannot be safe if you receive the parent class - the subclass may define methods that do not exist in the parent. But still, you can't override the method

Comment: Please, please try to use the right words. You CAN override a method in PHP, just not overload it.

Answer (score 0):

When I have a method that I may need to overload (which PHP does not support), I make sure that one of the method arguments (usually the last) is an array.  In this way I can pass whatever I need to. I can then test within the function for various array elements to tell me what routine in the method I need to perform, usually in a select/case.