# Silex 2.0 Unable to pass the Application $app to a UserServiceProvider

Tags: php, service, interface, silex, provider

I have been using the SimpleUser (https://github.com/jasongrimes/silex-simpleuser) addin for Silex(originally 1.3). I am in the process of upgrading My app to Silex 2.0. The UserProviderInterface in SimpleUser implements the ServiceProviderInterface and the ControllerProviderInterface. The former is now defined in Pimple not in Silex as it was in 1.3 and the argument of its register method is a Pimple container not a Silex Application (which extends the Pimple container class). PHPStorm marks this as a PHP fatal error ( Declaration must be compatible with the ServiceProviderInterface-->register(pimple: \Pimple\Container)). I am not sure whether the check in PHPStorm is simply too rigid or this is a serious problem.

Other posts indicate that you cannot simply override the Interface definitions ([Can you override interface methods with different, but "compatible", signatures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011512/can-you-override-interface-methods-with-different-but-compatible-signatures)) (also http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php).

I have just solved my problem. The Silex 2.0 Provider notes indicate that you can implement the register method with Container $app as the argument where $app is a Silex\Application instance. PHPStorm no longer objects to the register method in the UserServiceProvider. I am continuing to post this in case someone else comes across this problem.

Comment: Good question, good research, and good answer! It might be an idea to update your question with a concrete example, and provide a proper "answer" too.

Answer (score 0):

A bit bit of further information after further debugging. The SimpleUser UserServiceProvider was implemented for Silex 1.3 with the Silex\ServiceProviderInterface and the Silex\ControllerProviderInterface where the ServiceProviderInterface provided both register and boot methods.

In Silex 2.0, the ServiceProviderInterface only provides a register method and is now in the Pimple namespace. The BootableProviderInterface can provide the boot method and the ControlleProviderInterface the connect method and are located in the Silex\API namespace.

The SimpleUserProvider must implement all three to work in Silex2.0. The register() method now requires a Pimple\Container as its argument not a Silex\Application while the boot() and connect() methods still have an Silex\Application as the first argument.

Eg
class UserServiceProvider implements 
    ServiceProviderInterface, 
    BootableProviderInterface, 
    ControllerProviderInterface
{
    public function register(Container $app){
    ...
    }
    public function boot(Application $app) {
    ...
    }
    public function connect(Application $app) {
    ....
    }
    ...
}